# In Python, how to use GUI module file created in QtDesigner

Tags: python-3.x, qt-creator, pyqt5, qt-designer

I created a GUI with the hepl of QtCreator-->QtDesigner. The file is called mainwindow.ui. With the help of `pyuic5` I created `mainwindow.py`

```
pyuic5 mainwindow.ui > mainwindow.py
```

and this is how it looks like:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 300)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralWidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 341, 191))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 400, 23))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName("mainToolBar")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
```

and wanted to import that in my main script `main.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from mainwindow import *
import sys


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    instance = Ui_MainWindow()
    #instance.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

...but nothing happens when I run it. How should my main.py look like to use that gui module?

Comment: See the PyQt documentation: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it myself. To use a GUI file in Python, created in QtCreator called `mainwindow.py`, my `main.py` should look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from mainwindow import *
import sys

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    instance = Main()
    #instance.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My class Main(QMainWindow) must have a parent `QMainWindow` and not `QWidget` because `QWidget` doesn't have `setCentralWidget` method which is needed in mainwindow.py.